# My app works in Development Build, but crashes in Release build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

So In the past week, I've been workng on a simple android game aplication that allows single player and multi player, however the multiplayer is just a simple Lan game.(So that I can practice networking in unity, but I dont have to have a server for release). Which simply means the person who hosts the lan game, will not only act as a client but also as a server at the same time. The problem that I have is, I cannot upload the android app bundle to the playstore if it is in development build when I build the .aab file, because then for some reason the .aab file is not signed with my keystore. So that means I need to build it in release build, however then the game crashes, because for some reason the application cannot bind the port on 8080 (tried other ports such as 8008,8007, none of them work).Can anyone please help me out. I've spent my whole day debugging this, but I just can't make it to work. This is the method where I start the server. This is just for local game, but it doesnt matter, cause the crash happens whenever Im just trying to bind a port.

[image]

And this is the server code where the crash happens:

[image]

Tried Updating unity to latest release, problem didnt change.

Comment: While not an expert. Have you asked android to grant permission to open sockets for listening? I know it needs permissions for basically everything

Comment: Please include code as text, not as images.  There is a code format button, or include 4 spaces before each line (plus indentations).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.